# UIimageViewcontrollerproblem

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have a problem... 
In my view i have Image.If i click on image is go to nextView.

Please help in this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are showing image in a imageview please change its type to Uibutton just for easiness. Now add a method on press of this button, that calls the next view and set the image of the next view as the backgroundimage/image of your button.

Hope this helps,

thanks,

Madhup